# SQL row query from the schema

Tags: sql

I have a schema of players in a league which looks like the schema blow.

```
Player (playerid integer, mentorid integer, leagueid integer, pay integer)
League (leagueid integer, leaguename text)
```

I am trying to find the players who are not mentoring anyone. What would be the query for that?

(So I am basically looking to find the entries from  `playerid` column which are not present in `mentorid` column)

Comment: Downvoter please state the reason ?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from player
where playerid not in (select distinct mentorid from player)
```

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-select is useless for a `IN` or `NOT IN` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the schema here. The SQl query should be easy:

```
SELECT * FROM Player WHERE mentorid is NULL
```

This will simply give you the entries of players who do not have a mentorid i.e who are not mentoring anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate:
`SELECT a.playerid FROM Players a RIGHT JOIN Players b ON a.playerid = b.mentorid WHERE a.playerid IS NOT NULL`